# "Bad" GCC optimization performance

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, g++, mingw

I am trying to understand why using -O2 -march=native with GCC gives a slower code than without using them.
Note that I am using MinGW (GCC 4.7.1) under Windows 7.

Here is my code :

**struct.hpp :**

```
#ifndef STRUCT_HPP
#define STRUCT_HPP

#include <iostream>

class Figure
{
public:
    Figure(char *pName);
    virtual ~Figure();

    char *GetName();
    double GetArea_mm2(int factor);

private:
    char name[64];
    virtual double GetAreaEx_mm2() = 0;
};

class Disk : public Figure
{
public:
    Disk(char *pName, double radius_mm);
    ~Disk();

private:
    double radius_mm;
    virtual double GetAreaEx_mm2();
};

class Square : public Figure
{
public:
    Square(char *pName, double side_mm);
    ~Square();  

private:
    double side_mm;
    virtual double GetAreaEx_mm2();
};

#endif
```

**struct.cpp :**

```
#include <cstdio>
#include "struct.hpp"

Figure::Figure(char *pName)
{
    sprintf(name, pName);
}

Figure::~Figure()
{
}

char *Figure::GetName()
{
    return name;
}

double Figure::GetArea_mm2(int factor)
{
    return (double)factor*GetAreaEx_mm2();
}

Disk::Disk(char *pName, double radius_mm_) :
Figure(pName), radius_mm(radius_mm_)
{
}

Disk::~Disk()
{
}

double Disk::GetAreaEx_mm2()
{
    return 3.1415926*radius_mm*radius_mm;
}

Square::Square(char *pName, double side_mm_) :
Figure(pName), side_mm(side_mm_)
{
}

Square::~Square()
{
}

double Square::GetAreaEx_mm2()
{
    return side_mm*side_mm;
}
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include "struct.hpp"

double Do(int n)
{
    double sum_mm2 = 0.0;
    const int figuresCount = 10000;
    Figure **pFigures = new Figure*[figuresCount];

    for (int i = 0; i < figuresCount; ++i)
    {
        if (i % 2)
            pFigures[i] = new Disk((char *)"-Disque", i);
        else
            pFigures[i] = new Square((char *)"-Carré", i);
    }

    for (int a = 0; a < n; ++a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < figuresCount; ++i)
        {
            sum_mm2 += pFigures[i]->GetArea_mm2(i);
            sum_mm2 += (double)(pFigures[i]->GetName()[0] - '-');
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < figuresCount; ++i)
        delete pFigures[i];

    delete[] pFigures;

    return sum_mm2;
}

int main()
{
    double a = 0;
    
    StartChrono();      // home made lib, working fine
    a = Do(10000);
    double elapsedTime_ms = StopChrono();

    std::cout << "Elapsed time : " << elapsedTime_ms << " ms" << std::endl;

    return (int)a % 2;  // To force the optimizer to keep the Do() call
}
```

I compile this code twice :

## 1 : Without optimization

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -std=c++11 -c struct.cpp -o struct.o

mingw32-g++.exe  -o program.exe main.o struct.o -s

## 2 : With -O2 optimization

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2  -march=native -std=c++11 -c main.cpp -o main.o

mingw32-g++.exe -Wall -fexceptions -O2  -march=native -std=c++11 -c struct.cpp -o struct.o

mingw32-g++.exe  -o program.exe main.o struct.o -s

## 1 : Execution time :

1196 ms (1269 ms with Visual Studio 2013)

## 2 : Execution time :

1569 ms (403 ms with Visual Studio 2013) !!!!!!!!!!!!!

Using -O3 instead of -O2 does not improve the results.
I was, and I still am, pretty convinced that GCC and Visual Studio are equivalents, so I don't understand this huge difference.
Plus, I don't understand why the optimized version is slower than the non-optimized version with GCC.

Do I miss something here ?
**(Note that I had the same problem with genuine GCC 4.8.2 on Ubuntu)**

Thanks for your help

Comment: [OT]: Use `const char*` in your constructor instead of casting `const char *` to `char*`.

Comment: `sprintf(name, pName);` is dangerous...

Comment: Thanks, I am fully aware of that and thus, have no excuse :)

Answer (score 2):

Considering that I don't see the assembly code,  I'm going to speculate the following :

The allocation loop can be optimized (by the compiler) by removing the if clause and causing the following :

```
 for (int i=0;i <10000 ; i+=2)
 {
       pFigures[i] = new Square(...);
 }
 for (int i=1;i <10000 ; i +=2)
 {
       pFigures[i] = new Disk(...);
 }
```

Considering that the end condition is a multiple of 4 , it can be even more "efficient"

```
 for (int i=0;i < 10000 ;i+=2*4)
 {
     pFigures[i] = ...
     pFigures[i+2] = ...
     pFigures[i+4] = ...
     pFigures[i+6] = ...
 }
```

Memory wise this will make Disks to be allocated 4 by 4  an Squares 4 by 4 .

Now, this means they will be found in the memory next to each other.

Next, you are going to iterate the vector 10000 times in a normal order (by normal i mean index after index).

Think about the places where these shapes are allocated in memory.You will end up having 4 times more cache misses (think about the border example, when 4 disks and 4 squares are found in different pages, you will switch between the pages 8 times... in a normal case scenario you would switch between the pages only once).

This sort of optimization (if done by the compiler, and in your particular code) optimizes the time for Allocation , but not the time of access (which in your example is the biggest load).

Test this by removing the i%2 and see what results you get.

Again this is pure speculation, and it assumes that the reason for lower performance was a loop optimization.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this is a completely possible explanation. But it is strange that Visual Studio, on the contrary, manages to divide dramatically the execution time, no ? 
Moreover, it is a quite simple situation, it is strange that VS is so much better than GCC. Still speculating here.

Comment: Result of your suggestion (I allocate only Disks, no condition in the loop anymore) :
non optimized : 1258 ms
optimized : 675 ms (still more than VisualStudio with the condition...)

Seems that your speculation could be right, but still does not explain why VS does that good

Comment: maybe vs moves the for (int a ... ) loop inside the i loop , so instead of for(a) { for (i) {} } you get a for(i) { for(a) {} } which should be faster. Try moving the loop yourself and see if the results get any closer. I'm all out of other speculations :).

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you've got an issue unique to the combination of mingw/gcc/glibc on Windows because your code performs faster with optimizations on Linux where gcc is altogether more 'at home'.

On a fairly pedestrian Linux VM using gcc 4.8.2:

```
$ g++ main.cpp struct.cpp
$ time a.out

real    0m2.981s
user    0m2.876s
sys     0m0.079s

$ g++ -O2 main.cpp struct.cpp
$ time a.out

real    0m1.629s
user    0m1.523s
sys     0m0.041s
```

...and if you really take the blinkers off the optimizer by deleting `struct.cpp` and moving the implementation all inline:

```
$ time a.out

real    0m0.550s
user    0m0.543s
sys     0m0.000s
```